# How to repeat a code in R fulfilling a condition across repeats

Tags: r, conditional-statements, repeat

I need to repeat a code 24 times (for 24 different participants), making sure that overall, for each *Scene2* in each *Trial* and *Route*, I have the same number of 1 and 0 across the columns *Random* of each participant (i.e., *Part.1*, *Part.2*, *Part.3*, etc.) when the *Target* is equal to 0.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Scene2 = rep(c(1:10), times=9)
myDF2 <- data.frame(Scene2)
myDF2$Target <- rep(0,10, each=9)
myDF2$Target[myDF2$Scene2==7] <- 1
myDF2$Trial <- rep(c(1:9),each=10)
myDF2$Route <- rep(LETTERS[1:6], each=10, length=nrow(myDF2))

library(plyr)
myDF3 <- myDF2 %>% group_by(Trial, Route) %>%  mutate(Random = ifelse(myDF2$Target==0,sample(c(rep(0,5),rep(1,5))),1)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

I need to obtain something like this:

```
Scene2  Target  Trial   Route   Part.1  Part.2  Part.3  Part.4  …   Part.24 Tot.1   Tot.0
1       0       1       A       0       1       1       0           0       12      12
2       0       1       A       1       0       1       0           0       12      12
3       0       1       A       1       0       0       0           0       12      12
4       0       1       A       0       1       0       1           0       12      12
5       0       1       A       1       0       1       1           0       12      12
6       0       1       A       1       0       0       0           1       12      12
7       1       1       A       1       1       1       1           1       24      0
8       0       1       A       0       0       1       1           1       12      12
9       0       1       A       0       1       1       1           1       12      12
10      0       1       A       0       1       0       0           1       12      12
```

How to achieve this? Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would really like to help but I did not understand what is the problem and what do you want to achieve. Can you please explain more detailed or reformulate??

Comment: @Seymour, I would like to create the columns *Part.1*, *Part.2*, *Part.3*, etc. until *Part.24* in such a way that (1) for each trial and route, if Target==1, then *Part.* is equal to 1, if Target==0, then *part* could be equal to 0 or 1, such that I obtain in total five 1s, and five 0s, (2) across the *Part* from 1 to 24, when Target ==0, the total number of 1s (Tot.1) needs to be 12 and the total number of 0s (Tot.0) needs to be 12, when Target==1, then  the total number of 1s (Tot.1) needs to be 24 and the total number of 0s (Tot.0) needs to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's some conditional logic here that needs to meet particular specifications, I think this is easier to do with a function.

```
Scene2 = rep(c(1:10), times=9)
myDF2 <- data.frame(Scene2)
myDF2$Target <- rep(0,10, each=9)
myDF2$Target[myDF2$Scene2==7] <- 1
myDF2$Trial <- rep(c(1:9),each=10)
myDF2$Route <- rep(LETTERS[1:6], each=10, length=nrow(myDF2))

library(tidyverse)

fill_random_columns <- function(df, reps) {

    # Start a loop with a counter
    for (i in 1:reps) {
    # Create a vector of 1s and 0s for filling rows    
    bag <- c(rep(0, 12), rep(1, 12))
    # Build up conditional data frame of 1s and 0s   
    row_vector <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(df$Target, function(v) {
        if (v == 1) return(rep(1, reps))
        else (return(sample(bag, reps)))
        })))
    }
    # Create column names
    colnames <- lapply(1:reps, function(i) {paste0("Part.", i)})
    # Name columns and sum up rows
    row_vector <- row_vector %>%
        `colnames<-`(colnames) %>%
        mutate(Total = rowSums(.))
    # Attach to original data frame
    df <- bind_cols(df, row_vector)
    return(df)
}

myDF3 <- myDF2 %>%
    group_by(Trial, Route) %>%
    fill_random_columns(., 24)
```

Comment: your code works well accounting for the total number of 1s across participants (which needs to be 12 when Target==0, and 24 when Target==1). However, it doesn't account for the total number of 1s and 0s for each trial and route (which need to be five 0s and five 1s in total, with always 1 if Target==1).